# Pass claims from WebApp to API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, claims

I am developing a web application and want to pass some custom claim to the API. I have the following code to set a user claim and call the API. I am expecting to access this claim in the API, but it's not happening. Can someone help, please? How do we pass the claim and other identity information from a web application to the API.

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Privacy3()
        {
            SetClaim("db2");

            var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient("NewApi");
            var api = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/api/customer");

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(api);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<Customer>>(responseStream, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
                return View(data);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

  private ClaimsPrincipal SetClaim(string id)
        {
            if (id == null || id == "")
            {
                id = "db1";
            }
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = HttpContext.User;
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("db", id));

            return principal;
        }
```

My API code is as below

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //From Mr Browne

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

            services.AddDbContext<CustomerDataContext>((sp, options) =>
            {

                var requestContext = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
                var constr = GetConnectionStringFromRequestContext(requestContext);
                options.UseSqlServer(constr, o => o.UseRelationalNulls());

            });
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "AspNetCoreEfTest", Version = "v1" });
            });

        }


  private string GetConnectionStringFromRequestContext(HttpContext requestContext)
        {
            var host = requestContext.User;
            var dbname = "AspNetCoreEfTest";
            if (host.Claims.Count(e => e.Type == "db") > 0)
            {
                var db = host.Claims.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == "db").Value;
                if (db == "db1")
                {
                    dbname = "AspNetCoreEfTest";
                }
                else if (db == "db2")
                {
                    dbname = "AspNetCoreEfTestTwo";
                }
            }

            return "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=" + dbname + ";Integrated Security=true";
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried this [link](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html)?

Comment: Hi Tisa, Thank you for the link. I will try it. Do you have anything without identityserver. its a paid service now that too USD 12000 per year